# Linked List Implementation in C - Segmentation fault error

Tags: c

I am struggling to find the error in the following implementation of linked list.I am getting `segmentation fault` error when I append or add at beginning

Please Help me where I am doing wrong

#include

```
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node*link;
};

void append(struct node *p,int num)
{
    struct node *temp,*q;
    q=p;
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    temp->link=NULL;
    if(p==NULL)
        p=temp;
    else
    {
        while(q->link!=NULL)
            q=q->link;

        q->link=temp;
    }
}



int main()
{
    int i,choice,num,pos;
    struct node p;
    printf("Enter your choice\n");
    printf("1-Append\n2-Add At Beg\n3-Add after\n4-Delete\n5-Exit");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    while(choice!=5)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:printf("Enter the number\n");
                    scanf("%d",&num);
                    append(&p,num);
                    break;


        }
        printf("1-Append\n2-Add At Beg\n3-Add after\n4-Delete\n5-Exit");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code. Remove unnecessary parts.

Comment: Learn how to write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Removed unnecessary code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
struct node*p;
```

it should be

```
struct node p;
```

you're creating pointer to node. But don't initialize it later, so no node is created and it points to random location. Then you pass that as argument to your functions.
When you are dereferencig this pointer in your functions `p->` you have a segmentation fault.

In your `main` function you should have declaration of 'node', not `pointer to node`, and then pass node's address to function with `&` operator.
So your function declaration `void addatbeg(struct node *p,int num);` is fine but it should be called (after you declare node p):

```
addatbeg(&p,some_number);
```

Also, every function that makes use of p should be changed to treat p like a structure, not like pointer to structure.
What you did here is confused some information on linked lists.
Usually head of a `singly linked list` declared as a pointer to node. When I implemented sll myself I did that, too. Then you pass that pointer by reference to functions manipulating on linked list and it works fine.
On the other hand you got `doubly linked lists`, and there it is more convinient to treat head of `doubly linked list` as just another node, but without value.
You are trying to mix those ideas together without understanding ideas behind them. 
I gave you bunch of tips on how to make it work, but fixing it would mean that I have to rewrite your whole code.
And that's not the point since you should learn it yourself.

Comment: You need to make the corresponding changes to the other routines - display, count, etc. or the same thing will happen there as well.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to have one list element on the stack and the rest on the heap. If you add some elements at the beginning and some at the hand, how would you know which element not to free? Additionally this element gets lost when the function it is defined in ends.

Comment: @ebo And I don't think you get answer. I gave some tips on how given code could work. Not the best idea on implementing singly linked list. That's why I elaborated so much about reading how to do it correctly.

Comment: IMHO using a stack value here is even worse!

Comment: @ebo worse than what? I don't see any alternatives. And what's the reason keeping me from putting head of a sll on the stack, when it's in main? One less thing to free.

Comment: Also the question was about finding bug in the code. I found it, fixed it, gave few alternative solutions and a couple of implementation tips, and it's still not a good answer? Please...

Answer (score 3):

do

```
struct node*p=NULL;
```

call append like this-

```
append(&p,num);
```

We do this as we want to keep the pointer to the first node of our link list with us. By doing append(p,num), a copy of the pointer goes into our method and the changes to p are lost when that method returns.

and write the append routine as-

```
void append(struct node **p,int num)
{
   struct node *temp,*q;
   q=*p;
   temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp->data=num;
   temp->link=NULL;
   if(*p==NULL)
   {
        *p=temp;
        printf("here");
    }
  else
   {
       while(q->link!=NULL)
        q=q->link;

       q->link=temp;
   }
}
```

do similarly for add routine.

Comment: You can eliminate the special case in your `append()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Final edit:
User vaibhav caught it: `struct node *p` is uninitialized and may not be NULL even if the list is empty.

Just for general enjoyment, the clang static analyser seems to get it:

```
clang -Wall --analyze lists.c
lists.c:13:5: warning: Assigned value is garbage or undefined
  q = *p;
    ^ ~~
1 warning generated.
```

---

> void append(struct node *p,int num);

While the algorithms themselves seem fine, there is a problem in the way you handle the `p`-argument. You pass the pointer `p` by value, which means changes to `*p` will change the allocated memory, but changes to `p` itself will not be propagated to the calling context.

The correct method to handle this case would be:

> void append(struct node **p, int num)
>   {
>     *p = temp;
>   }

```
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node*link;
};

void append(struct node **p,int num)
{
  struct node *temp,*q;
  q = *p;
  temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp->data = num;
  temp->link = NULL;
  if(*p == NULL)
    *p = temp;
  else
    {
      while(q->link != NULL)
        q = q->link;

      q->link = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
  struct node *p;

  append(&p, 1);
  append(&p, 2);
  append(&p, 3);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to use the signature `void append(struct node *p,int num);` only. What changes should I make I make in `main()`.I tried `struct node p;` and then passing address as `addatbeg(&p,num)` but even that doesn't help.

Comment: The problem with `append` is the initialisation of the list. You can disallow NULL for `append` and use a special initializer method. Or you can use a `list` type which holds a pointer to the first list element and can be constructed without a value.

Comment: You can eliminate the special case in your `append()` function.